# Xamarin VideoView Image Source

Tags: xamarin, android-videoview

For a xamarin project, I am using CrossMediaManager from https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager , it works fine for playing video and audio. I have a video view on the form which displays video for a video url, but for Audio it remains blank and black.
How can I set it source to some image file, so it looks bit better. Setting Source property doesnt work.  The image file does exists in both the plateforms as we are using it for some reasons also.
I tried doing using code.

```
videoPlayer.Source = "SomeImageFile";
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that would make me think image files are supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a image to cover the VideoView when it play the audio.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <mm:VideoView x:Name="video" ShowControls="True" />
        <Image Source="pink.jpg" />

    </Grid>
    <Button Clicked="BtnPlayLocal_Clicked" Text="play local video" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
  private void BtnPlayLocal_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //audio
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");

        // video
        //http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4 
    }
```

[image]